# Websocket support in a web application

Tags: spring, websocket, atmosphere

I want to develop a web application using websocket.

I have found two solutions for this task:

Using Spring websocket (included in Spring 4) - I am already familiarized with Spring

Using Atmosphere framework - I've read the docs, it seems to be a mature framework.

I want from the websocket framework to provide a fallback-support in case when the
browser isn't HTML5 compliant, also, I need a client-library for android.

I see that Atmosphere provides support for Socket.IO library, which I want to use on
browser client side. I see that Spring websocket provides only SockJS support over STOMP.

Can I use the same library, Socket.IO, in Spring websocket?

Do you recommend me to use Atmosphere + Spring (for building the RESTFul API) in the same
project?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest going for the WebSocket support in Spring. If you are already using Spring, this will give you a similar programming model plus all these features:

- Fallback options with [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)
- Subprotocol support with [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/)
- Integration with full blown STOMP broker (like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com))
- HttpSession and WebSocket Session sync (using [Spring Session](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session))
- WebSocket security (in the upcoming [Spring Security 4](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/preview-spring-security-websocket-support))
- SockJS Java client (for application to application communication and performance testing, haven't tried it on Android yet but might work)
- Runtime Monitoring
- Active community with fast response times to requests

The WebSocket support has been around since Spring 4, tested and refined for over a year now. A production ready solution which I'm using in my projects.